# The bound class changes but the div won't move

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a sidebar with 3 moveable panels. I move it by changing the bound `:class` to the parent `<div>` by using `-translate-x-(amount)` (using TailwindCSS classes). When I click the menu button, I see that the DOM does react and change the class with the correct `translate-x-` value yet the panel won't move.

Link to sandbox (From some reason it works on the sandbox - it also works randmoly on my PC but rarely): https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cdn-o38n6?file=/src/App.vue

This is the code:

```
<template>
    <div class="h-screen flex">
        <div class="flex container w-40 h-80 bg-black mx-auto my-auto text-black overflow-hidden">
            <div class="sidebar container flex transform duration-1000" :class="position">

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-gray-300">
                    <button @click="currentIndex++">Menu item</button>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 bg-blue-300 transform duration-1000">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>

                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex++">
                        Menu item
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-red-300">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            sidebarWidth: 40,
            currentIndex: 0
        }),
        computed: {
            position() {
                if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
                    
                    return 'translate-x-0'
                } else {                
                    
                    return `-translate-x-${this.sidebarWidth * this.currentIndex}`}
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer if anyone in the future will also encounter such weird behavior:

The issue is with Tailwind's JIT mode: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

It compiles classes on demand - only what he sees in use while building the app, and in my case the bound classes are not immediately used - only after the click event, so Tailwind probably doesn't see these classes with JIT mode, so I removed the line `mode: jit,` from `tailwind.config.js` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

To track the reason of your error I see to have a demo version of your code like [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

**Demo**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
     sidebarWidth: 40,
            currentIndex: 0,
    message: 'TailWindCSS Dev',
          model: null,
  },
  
          computed: {
            position() {
                if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
                    
                    return 'translate-x-0'
                } else {                
                    
                    return `-translate-x-${this.sidebarWidth * this.currentIndex}`}
            }
        },
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
   <div class="flex justify-center">
     <p class="text-3xl text-yellow-600">{{message}}</p>
  </div>
  
  <template>
    <div class="h-screen flex">
        <div class="flex container w-40 h-80 bg-black mx-auto my-auto text-black overflow-hidden">
            <div class="sidebar container flex transform duration-1000" :class="position">

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-gray-300">
                    <button @click="currentIndex++">Menu item</button>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 bg-blue-300 transform duration-1000">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>

                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex++">
                        Menu item
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-red-300">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
  
</div>
```

Comment: this is awesome! thank you. But how did you make it work? The main issue of my question was not that I can't run a snippet - because I can run it on my local dev environment - but the panels aren't moving at all although the DOM class updates - did you find out why? Because your code seems identical to mine

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, let me know a codesanbox link for your code

Comment: Oh I got now! I added link to sandbox in the main post

Comment: I visited it, the project had error and also I see to post the error message you got from the console when you meet it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save the work I thought it saves it automatically - now I updated the link. Also, I found the issue - you can see my answer